# How to catch JavaScript errors and warnings for page in WebView in UWP

Tags: javascript, c#, webview, uwp

I would like to catch and log any JavaScript errors or Warnings from pages I host in a [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview) inside my UWP app.

I would like to be able to catch these errors for *any* webpage I load in my app's WebView.

I know that Visual Studio has a mechanism to attach to a UWP apps' WebView and log the JavaScript errors, but I would like to do the same without Visual Studio.

This answer for [JavaScript error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970475/get-all-javascript-errors-on-page-javascript-error-handling) shows how to do this in plain JavaScript, but I need to know how and when to inject code like this into a WebView, or if there is a better way to do this.

If possible, I would like to have something similar to the JavaScript console in F12 tools, but I at least need to be able to get JavaScript errors and warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This answer for JavaScript error handling shows how to do this in plain JavaScript, but I need to know how and when to inject code like this into a WebView, or if there is a better way to do this.

You could try to use [InvokeScriptAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/webview_invokescriptasync) with the JavaScript `eval` function to inject content into the web page when Navigation Completed.

Then, if you want to get the error message in your app, you could use  `window.external.notify` with a string parameter to send information back to your app. To receive these messages, handle the [ScriptNotify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify) event.

I made a simple code sample for your reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--this is my local web page HTMLPage1.html-->
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input  value="click" onclick="test1()" type="button"/>
</body>
</html>
```

```xml
<WebView x:Name="webview" NavigationCompleted="webview_NavigationCompleted" ScriptNotify="webview_ScriptNotify" Source="ms-appx-web:///HTMLPage1.html"></WebView>
```

```cs
private void webview_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    string msg = e.Value;
}

private async void webview_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    string functionString = "window.onerror = function(error, url, line) {window.external.notify( 'ERR:'+error+' url'+url+' Line: '+line);};";
    var ret = await webview.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
}
```