# Catch all errors clientside sent from any service

Tags: javascript, vuex, feathersjs

I want to write a vuejs component that displays any errors from the server but I don't want to have to call it in every catch of every service call. How can I simply catch every error sent to the client?

Thanks.

I'm using feathers-vuex and want to handling through that if possible and not pure javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all javascript errors on page/javascript error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970475/get-all-javascript-errors-on-page-javascript-error-handling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle all errors returned form the Feathers API in an [Application level error hook](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html#application-hooks) of the Feathers client application:

```
feathersClient.hooks({
  error (context) {
    showErrorPopup(error.message);
  }
});
```